# Invalid form POST data error on ctools modal

Tags: ajax, comments, chaos-tool-suite

I am using [Node Comment Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_comment_block) and [Ajax Comments](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_comments) to put comments in block and ajaxify them, and comment system is working fine, on content page I have a link which opens node edit form using ctools modal, node form on ctools works fine too. Issue comes when  a user replies on a comment and then comes back to use the node form on ctools modal through the link, in that case the form opens fine but on submitting user gets

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred
HTTP Result Code: 200
Path: /system/ajax
```

Meanwhile there is a watchdog entry for the same which says `Invalid form POST data.`

WatchDog trigger point seems to be includes/ajax.inc, inside ajax_get_form()

```
function ajax_get_form() {
  $form_state = form_state_defaults();

  $form_build_id = $_POST['form_build_id'];
  watchdog('ajax', $form_build_id, array(), WATCHDOG_WARNING);

  // Get the form from the cache.
  $form = form_get_cache($form_build_id, $form_state);
  if (!$form) {
    // If $form cannot be loaded from the cache, the form_build_id in $_POST
    // must be invalid, which means that someone performed a POST request onto
    // system/ajax without actually viewing the concerned form in the browser.
    // This is likely a hacking attempt as it never happens under normal
    // circumstances, so we just do nothing.
    watchdog('ajax', 'Invalid form POST data.', array(), WATCHDOG_WARNING);
    drupal_exit();
  }...
```

I am getting $form_build_id on node form submission, not sure if it is valid one or outdated, also I am not getting clue how ajax comments are creating issue with node form. Any pointers?

**Update**

function `ajax_get_form()` only gets invoked from node edit form submission on ctools when there is reply on comment section, if there is no activity in comments, `ajax_get_form()` does not even invoke.